# How to start and stop spark Context Manually

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am new to spark.In my current spark application script, I can send queries to spark in-memory saved table and getting the desired result using spark-submit.The problem is, each time spark context stops automatically after completing result. I want to send multiple queries sequentially.for that I need to keep alive spark context. how could I do that ? my point is

```
Manual start and stop sparkcontext by user
```

kindly suggest me.I am using pyspark 2.1.0.Thanks in advance

Comment: if every time you are sending the query using spark-submit it will start your new spark application (JVM) and whenever your job completed it will shut down the jvm. So more better approach is to create a single spark application and accept your queries using jdbc or http.

Comment: thanks for your reply can you clarify me a bit or it will be a great help to give me some resource links.

Comment: ok so simply create a http sever using akka-http and one of the http service will accept the query as string and that http service will run your spark job and store result back to hdfs or if result will be small u can simply revert it to calling service.

Answer (score 20):

To answer your question, this works

```
import pyspark

# start
sc = pyspark.SparkContext()

#stop
sc.stop()
```

Comment: thanks but this format did not work for me .My code is
from pyspark import SparkConf,SparkContext
conf=SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("Friendstest")
sc=SparkContext(conf=conf)
#some code here 
sc.stop()
this sc.stop() produced me same result. May be you are right but am i missing something . a good clarification will help me

Comment: if I use Thread.sleep(86400000); after the code . will this trick do the job. I didn't try it yet. looking for a suggestion. I have found this 

http://bigdatawhizkid.blogspot.com/2016/02/simple-hack-to-keep-sparkcontext-and.html

Answer (score 3):

**Try this code:**

```
conf = SparkConf().setAppName("RatingsHistogram").setMaster("local")

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf)
```

This ensures to don;t have always stop your context and at the same time, if existing Spark Context are available, it will be reused.